# Why don't we use * while we create the object of NSRange

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Can anybody tell me that Why don't we use * with NSRange object.Whenever i use * with NSRange it gives error why it's giving error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `NSRange` is a struct, not a class. Structs are value types, and therefore you do not use pointers with them like you do with class instances (`*` is the pointer dereferencing operator).

Comment: You can always refer to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html), or in Xcode right-click on the name and choose **Jump to Definition**.

Comment: Actually you can use pointers to structs, but not necessarily :)

Comment: @Vladimir: Yeah of course, hopefully my edit makes it slightly clearer.

Comment: Sadly there's no naming convention, so you just have to remember or ask Xcode. Quickest way is to double click on the word (such as NSRange) with option/alt pressed. For NSRange the first three words in the box that pops are "Abstract: a structure". So if it's a struct[ure], it'll say right there.

Comment: When you pull up autocomplete in XCode it will tell you. Start typing NSRange then hit esc and you should see NSRange in the autocomplete list with a T next to it letting you know its a typedef. If you try and do the same same with NSString you will see a C letting you know it is a class. There are others like f letting you know it is a function like NSMakeRange.

Comment: @Joe: Thanks, that's very cool, at last I know what those little letters mean :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the structure of NSRange :

```
typedef struct _NSRange {
      NSUInteger location;
      NSUInteger length;
} NSRange;
```

Now tell me do you think we required any pointer ? why we required the pointer ? If you can give the answer than that is your solution.

Comment: i think structs are stored in memory via a stack

Comment: Upto some extend you are right. Apple has created all the Data Type based on their usage.

Comment: structs is value type and the class is reference type.